# Can i use 戻りました or 帰って来ました after being offline for a long period to say i'm back online?

Tags: translation, words, culture

What do i say when i want to say i'm back online after being offline during a long period of time? Can i use 戻りました and/or 帰って来ました?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both are fine.  Both convey your feeling that whatever online forum you are coming back to is your "home."

Both expressions also convey a certain amount of respect, and as a result they sound a bit formal. It's a kind of expressions that you can use to seniors, teachers, colleagues, etc. If you are aiming for more informal expression to friends, I suggest 戻ってきた(よ) or 帰ってきた.

Comment: Could you even use ただいま?